# WordPress home page title

Tags: wordpress, seo, title

My homepage's title is being displayed as the title of the last blog post created.

The code is:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

So from my understanding that should display the blog title (set in general settings) on the homepage.

But its not. Its displaying the most recent post title.

What do i need to look for?

Comment: Im beginning to wonder if I am editing the wrong file. Im editing the header.php file in the theme directory.

Comment: The problem  was actually that a plugin was writing over the code in the header.php file. But I have upvoted the most helpful answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_title()` is used to display the title of the page being displayed, but it uses the query results to get its value. So if you are executing a loop on many posts (which you obviously are on your homepage) and you don't reset it, you will get the title of the last post in your  loop... logical. 
Besides, note that the homepage is index.php in your theme, it is not a real page in WordPress. So it hasn't got a title. So `wp_title()` can't be of any use for you here. 
Basically, your homepage has not got any title. So if this template is both for your homepage and other pages, you need to do a conditional check :

Is this homepage? (use `is_home()`)
A. Yes, echo "Welcome on my great website"
B. No, wp_title(), which will echo the title of the page you are on...

Do you get it?

Comment: Ok. I get the wp_title bit. but bloginfo('name') should still return the name of the blog shouldn't it?

I have removed everything and just left that in, but its still returning nothing, while on the other pages it works.

Comment: Just noting that it was actually a plugin overwritng wordpresses default behaviour. I uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're executing two functions here -- [wp_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title), which retrieves the title of the *page* the visitor is currently on, and thereafter [bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo), which with the argument 'name' indeed fetches your blog's name as set in the configuration.

However, there's a slight error in your code; you'd get the desired result as follows:

```
<title>
    <?php
        wp_title('&#124;', true, 'right');
        bloginfo('name');
    ?>
</title>
```

You should read about the parameters for `wp_title` on the WP Codex; the | gives you a delimiter, for example, and 'right' tells the function where to output said separator.

Note: I'd advise you to display both the post title and blog name, as only the blog name on every single page is both unhelpful for visitors and yields por results in search engine results.

Comment: thats doing the exact same thing.  blofinfo('name') isn't pulling the blogs name on the home page though. Its pulling the title of the most recent post.  I have checked this by removing the wp_title(); function

Comment: Perhaps this applies to your situation? (Also see barakadam's answer):

If you are using a custom homepage with custom loops and stuff, you will have an empty wp_title. Here goes a neat hack to add the description/tagline at the wp_title place on homepage:

`<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_home() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>`

(Excerpt from the [wp_title codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title))

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem! Error in your code : remove `>` after `<?php` (you have written `<?php>`) so this :

```
<?php> bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

should now become this :

```
<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

And it will work !

Comment: Voting this as answered would be nice! It was a syntax error. Did you read my answer?

Comment: I read your answer. someone else had already provided that answer. and it didn't solve the issue.   the issue is that when that is on the homepage. with the right syntax. it is still returning the latest post title. not the blog name